# When disabling the DiskCache plugin, images fail to display.

Tags: c#, stream, imageresizer

I've been using the basic ImageResizer library with the DiskCache plugin.  Due to disk space, I've needed to move to using a CDN to free up space on the webserver.

To prevent creating a local disk cache, as per the docs, I've added the `enabled` property and set to `false` in the config:

```
<diskcache dir="~/Content/Resize" enabled="false" />
```

Unfortunately now, nothing appears when requesting the image.  After enabling all exceptions, I've managed to narrow down to this routine in `ImageResizer.Plugins.Basic`:

```
public static void SaveJpeg(Image b, Stream target, int quality)
{
  if (quality < 0)
    quality = 90;
  if (quality > 100)
    quality = 100;
  using (EncoderParameters encoderParams = new EncoderParameters(1))
  {
    using (EncoderParameter encoderParameter = new EncoderParameter(Encoder.Quality, (long) quality))
    {
      encoderParams.Param[0] = encoderParameter;

      // NOTE: this would appear to be the trigger
      b.Save(target, DefaultEncoder.GetImageCodeInfo("image/jpeg"), encoderParams);
      // NOTE
    }
  }
}
```

> System.NotSupportedException
>   "Specified method is not supported."
>   "at System.Web.HttpResponseStream.get_Position()"

Can anyone help with this issue?

[image: Stack]

Comment: HttpResponse can't seek that is why the Position property throws (it does not support it). It looks like the ImageResizer library requires a target stream that can do seeks. Save the image to a temporary stream first (MemoryStream, perhaps), before writing to your actual target stream.

Comment: @Ilian Pinzon do you know if this is new behaviour? I'm assuming at one stage the library did work saving to the target (response) stream...

Comment: I bet it's because you disabled the Diskacche plugin. It probably wrote to a FileStream before.

Answer (score 0):

> This is fixed in the latest version (4.1.9).

This is due to the `DefaultEncoder` plugin attempting to write the image directly to the response stream.  Perhaps a change in the .NET Framework prevents seeking on the response stream breaking the save routine.

There is a way around the problem which involves using a patched version of the plugin (thanks to @Ilian Pinzon).  This writes to a temporary stream before writing to the response stream:

```
private static void SaveJpeg(Image image, Stream target, int quality)
{
    if (quality < 0)
        quality = 90; //90 is a very good default to stick with.

    if (quality > 100)
        quality = 100;

    using (EncoderParameters p = new EncoderParameters(1))
    {
        using (EncoderParameter ep = new EncoderParameter(Encoder.Quality, quality))
        {
            p.Param[0] = ep;

            ImageCodecInfo info = ImageResizer.Plugins.Basic.DefaultEncoder.GetImageCodeInfo("image/jpeg");

            if (!target.CanSeek)
            {
                using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(_streamCopyBuffer))
                {
                    image.Save(ms, info, p);
                    ms.WriteTo(target);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                image.Save(target, info, p);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I've created a quick n' dirty gist which drafts a version of the plugin with the fix and config changes to use it.

https://gist.github.com/restlessmedia/9401155f40bd12d40d6affb53c4231b5